# How to build $\hat F(t^2) = F(t)$?

Tags: calculus

I have F(t) (marked by red color): 
[image]

C and r are constants;

How to build a function $\hat F(x)$ which will satisfy $\hat F(t^2) = F(t)$?
I think $\hat F(x)$ will look like blue line on the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the graph I can tell your $F$ is defined as the segment line $y=-(C/r)x+C$  for $t$ between $0$ and $r$, and the horizontal line $y=0$ for $t \geq r$. Your $\hat{F}$ satisfies $\hat{F}(t^2)=F(t)$, so for $0 \leq t^2 \leq r^2$ it satisfies $\hat{F}(t^2) = -(C/r)t+C$ and $\hat{F}(t^2) = 0$ for $t^2 \geq r^2$. The former can be read as $\hat{F}(t) = -(C/r)\sqrt{t}+C$ for $0 \leq t \leq r^2$, whereas the latter is $\hat{F}(t)=0$ for $t \geq r^2$. Hence
$$
\hat{F}(t) = 
\begin{cases}
-(C/r)\sqrt{t}+C, & 0 \leq t \leq r^2 \\
0, & t \geq r^2.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Is $F$ defined on $[0, \infty)$ ? If yes, then put

$\hat F(t) = F(\sqrt{t}).$

Comment: Stupid me. Thanks for your answer!